# $routeProvider, injection in angularjs, not able to identify the error

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

On clicking register, just the url changes and not taked to register.html or displayed the content

[image: Screenshot]

**html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<title></title>
<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="Script/Scc.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="sampleApp">
First Name<input type="text" ng-model="reg.firstName" /><br />
Last Name<input type="text" ng-model="reg.lastName" />  <br />          
<a href="#Register"> Register </a> 
 </body>
```

**Scc.js**

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute']);
sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when('/#Register', {
        templateUrl: '/register.html',
        controller: 'registerController'
    })
  }]);
sampleApp.controller('registerController', function ($scope,$route) {
var reg = {
    firstName: 'Mmm',
    lastName: 'Nnn',
};
$scope.reg = reg;
});
```

**register.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Registration</h2>
First Name is{{ reg.firstName }}<br />
Last Name is   {{reg.lastName}}
</body>
</html>
```

not able to retrieve the textbox content and display it in register.html...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `ng-view` directive in your html to indicate where the template should be injected. Something like `<div ng-view></div>`.

And your `register.html` shouldn't be a full HTML document, it should be a partial template contaning just the data that needs to be injected.

And you don't need the `#` in route:

```
when('/Register', {
    templateUrl: '/register.html',
    controller: 'registerController'
});
```

Make sure the path to template is correct.

Comment: hii, can you be more specific about ng-view and HTML doc..?

Comment: @PraveenKrishnaP your register.html should only contain the current  contents inside the `<body>`. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

Comment: did the changes as you said, T J, here is the result [link](https://i.imgsafe.org/834cce0df7.png) Plz hav a look..

Comment: @PraveenKrishnaP the current  problem is resolved right? The content is being loaded... Looks like you have some error... check your console... We can't help you fix other issues based on screenshot... Maybe create an online demo like jsfiddle or plunkr...